# Facebook Graph API, get page_fans returns a negative value

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get a page number of fans through graph API, this is my call:

`{page_id}/insights/page_fans`

but I'm getting negative values as follows:

`"data": [
    {
      "name": "page_fans",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": -1,
          "end_time": "2017-09-17T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": -2,
          "end_time": "2017-09-18T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ]`

I couldn't find anything about it in the docs. Can anybody explain that negative number?

Comment: No, this makes no sense - a zero is the lowest value you should get, for pages that did not have any fans yet at that point in time. Suggest you file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: @Silvia did you figure out the error?